# Angular - User Cannot select an option in a dynamic dropdown using *ngFor and NgModel

Tags: angular, ngfor, ngmodel

I have a dropdown that contains a list of dynamic options that change based on a rule in another typescript(stixService.ts) that are called and appear in the dropdown .The different options appear in the dropdown but the user cannot select one and then have it appear in the input field instead of the placeholder "Choose a Selector".

Here is my code:

```
<select type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="newSelector" name="selectors" id="selectors">
 <option>Choose a Selector</option>
 <option *ngFor="let item of stixService.granularMarkingSelectors" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share stixService.granularMarkingSelectors code?

Comment: Sharing a stackblitz so we can check what's going on would be nice, we can't reproduce the problem with the code you provided.